Date Slicer Not Filtering Correctly in Power BI
I developed a date slicer to filter by specific date ranges using the following DAX measure:
Period_Selection_Measure = 
  VAR Period_Selected = SELECTEDVALUE(Slicer[Order_By])

  -- Today
  VAR Today_Selection = IF(MAX(Sales[Date]) = TODAY(), 1, 0)

  -- Current week
  VAR Current_Week = IF(WEEKNUM(MAX(Sales[Date])) = WEEKNUM(TODAY()) &&
                     YEAR(MAX(Sales[Date])) = YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 0)

  -- Previous week
  VAR Previous_Week = IF(WEEKNUM(MAX(Sales[Date])) = WEEKNUM(TODAY()) - 1 &&
                      YEAR(MAX(Sales[Date])) = YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 0)

  -- Current month
  VAR Current_Month = IF(MONTH(MAX(Sales[Date])) = MONTH(TODAY()) &&
                       YEAR(MAX(Sales[Date])) = YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 0)

  -- Previous month
  VAR Previous_Month = IF(MONTH(MAX(Sales[Date])) = MONTH(TODAY()) - 1 &&
                        YEAR(MAX(Sales[Date])) = YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 0)

  -- All dates (ALL)
  VAR All_Dates = IF(MAX(Sales[Date]) IN ALL('Date'[Date]), 1, 0)

RETURN 
    SWITCH(
        Period_Selected,
        1, Today_Selection,      -- Option 1: Today
        2, Current_Week,         -- Option 2: Current week
        3, Previous_Week,        -- Option 3: Previous week
        4, Current_Month,        -- Option 4: Current month
        5, Previous_Month,       -- Option 5: Previous month
        6, All_Dates,            -- Option 6: All dates
        0                        -- Default value
    )

However, the date slicer is showing an error and isn’t filtering as expected.
Does anyone have an idea on how to troubleshoot this issue or what could be causing the slicer to fail?


Hard to determine without seeing your PBIX. Do a debug test, add a table visual with Sales[Date] and [Period_Selection_Measure] to check the measure is working correctly. You should consider using a Date table in your model.
